# почему не работает цикл?

Tags: javascript, for

данные в str получены из тэга input(text)

```
 for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++ ) {
 if ((str.charCodeAt([i]) > 47) && (str.charCodeAt([i])) < 58) {
   number = true;
 }
 if ((str.charCodeAt([i]) > 64) && (str.charCodeAt([i]) < 91)) {
   aletter = true;
 }
 if ((str.charCodeAt([i]) >= 0) && (str.charCodeAt([i]) < 48)) {
   val.style.background = 'Yellow';
   outMessage(error);
   return false;
 } 
 if((str.charCodeAt([i]) > 57) && (str.charCodeAt([i]) < 65)) {
    val.style.background = 'Yellow';
    outMessage(error);
    return false;
 } 
 if (str.charCodeAt([i]) > 90 ) {
    val.style.background = 'Yellow';
    outMessage(error);
    return false;
  }
  console.log(str[i]);
}
if (number && aletter) {
 val.style.background = 'Blue';
 outMessage(legal);
 return true;
}
```

Comment: разобрался, вместо str.charCodeAt([i]) нужно было прописать str.value.charCodeAt([i])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Строчные латинские буквы начинаются с 97.

```js
function checkString(str) {
  var number = false;
  var aletter = false;
  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    console.log(str[i], str.charCodeAt([i]));
    if ((str.charCodeAt([i]) > 47) && (str.charCodeAt([i])) < 58) {
      number = true;
    }
    if ((str.charCodeAt([i]) > 64) && (str.charCodeAt([i]) < 91)) {
      aletter = true;
    }
    if ((str.charCodeAt([i]) >= 0) && (str.charCodeAt([i]) < 48)) {
      return false;
    }
    if ((str.charCodeAt([i]) > 57) && (str.charCodeAt([i]) < 65)) {
      return false;
    }
    if (str.charCodeAt([i]) > 90) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return number && aletter;
}

console.log(checkString("AZ09a"));
```

Comment: не помогло, ничего в консоль не выводится

Comment: @xalex строка какая?

Comment: строка для чего? любые символы, но по идее проверка на латиницу и номера, остальное выход

Comment: @xalex строка какая проверяется?

Comment: любая, пароль из инпута

Comment: @xalex Пример видите в ответе? По-моему, все понятно.

Comment: если вы имеете ввиду замену let на var то не помогло. Очевидного ответа не нашел.(функции закоментировал)

Comment: @xalex Строчные латинские буквы начинаются с 97.

Comment: разобрался, вместо str.charCodeAt([i]) нужно было прописать str.value.charCodeAt([i])

большое спасибо за подсказку и помощь

Answer (score 0):

разобрался, вместо str.charCodeAt([i]) нужно было прописать str.value.charCodeAt([i])

Comment: В таком случае `str` - это не строка. Писать в функции `str.value` - плохо. Правильнее вызывать функцию соответствующим образом `checkString(x.value)`.

Comment: данные получены из тэга инпут/текст. Простите за назойливость, но чем плохо делать такую запись?

Comment: Потому что функция должна заниматься своим делом. Если она проверяет строку на корректность, она должна эту строку и получать, а не input.

Comment: функция получает данные из инпута, в инпут вводит пользователь, простите я не очень понимаю вашу мысль, а как пользователь введет данные минуя тэги разметки?

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BF_%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8